# Create Vector of Factors from random labelling of rows of a data frame

Tags: r, random, bioconductor

I have a dataframe with 110 rows which is the pData from a microarray experiment expressionset object. I want to create a vector of factors with 2 levels, randomly assigned to the rows (which represent the samples of the experiment). For example, if there are 110 rows corresponding to 110 subjects in the experiment I would want 55 rows to be set as “G0” and 55 as “G1”. These groups are used in a subsequent function.
I am currently trying the following which is wrapped within a function I am trying to modify:

```
# makes a numeric vector of the number of subjects/rows in the pData
sml<-rep(0,length(colnames(eset))

# ‘populate’ sml with G0 & G1 
sml[sample(sml,(length(sml)/2))]<-"G0"
sml[sample(sml,(length(sml)/2))]<-"G1"
label <- as.factor(sml)
```

How do I sample such that the G1 group completes the length of sml and leaves the positions already assigned as G0 untouched?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct answer

```
eset <- matrix(NA, ncol = 110, nrow = 1)
good <- sample(
  rep(
    factor(c("G0", "G1")),
    ncol(eset) %/% 2
  )
)
table(good)
```

this is the bad example

```
bad <- sample(c("G0", "G1"), ncol(eset), replace = TRUE)
table(bad)
```

Comment: Awesome, this one I didn't know!